Alternatives to mathml for PDF Tagging
I have recently spend some time studying the tagging project's literature and a bit of the code at GitHub and I don't see any difficulties of changing some of the longer documents I am working on to provide artifact and alt values where needed, etc. A stumbling block is the suggestion that math needs to be provided as mathml. Are you kidding me?
I think a more convenient approach would be as follows:

Use an LLM to provide text or a sound file for every math display block. This is not as hard as it sounds and can be automated through pre-processing of .tex files.

Find a way to communicate this to a screen reader as alt, i.e., treat the math block as an artifact and play the sound .mp3 file or let the screen reader read the "text" used for the voice file.

I experimented with a simple continuous fraction equation. Here is the LLM text:
text = ("X equals a zero plus the fraction one over a one plus the fraction one over a two plus the fraction one over a three plus the fraction one over a four.")


Here is the LaTeX code:
\begin{gather}
  x = a_0 + \cfrac{1}{a_1 
          + \cfrac{1}{a_2 
          + \cfrac{1}{a_3 + \cfrac{1}{a_4}}}}
\end{gather}



and here is an image of the compiled code:

Here is the .mp3 file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10hHuYxaPbjzQuf69wVcQS8KDVgaY-50Y/view.
If you listen to it you can understand some of the problems facing visually impaired users. Although easy for us to see $a_0$ reading aloud "a zero" is confusing; is this 1 zero?
One should be more careful to add better and and longer explanatory texts in the preceding paragraphs. As Halmos and others said once you finish your write-up read it aloud to make sure the text and the math form a continuum. So, maybe this method also helps improve one's writing abilities.
One could use a similar method for tables.
So, the question is: Are there tags available for such an arrangement? I can think of artifact to ignore the math or an ignore tag and somehow an alt="text....", so something like
\begin[text="...",lang='en',sound=1.mp3]{altmath} % inserted by pre-processor
  \begin{gather}
  ......
  \end{gather}
\end{altmath} % inserted by pre-processor


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Yes mathml is not the only option (but imho the best for complex mathematic). One can imagine other/additional resources like normal text, the LaTeX source (that is already there), or a mp3 file, or a braille text or ...
(I wouldn't add such resources through lots of keys in some optional argument. Imho that is overloading the interfaces but instead add them if they are found and fit the equation by using (similar to the mathml handling) through a hash, but such interface questions can be discussed.)
But the main question is not how to add such resources but how to use them properly. If you look around you will find many tools that advertise that they can produce nice accessible PDFs, but you will not find tools that advertise that they are particularly good at using accessible PDFs. You do not find much documentation how the different options interact or can be configured. You do not find good descriptions how user actually navigate such a document. It took ages to get a tool setup to demonstrate the use of the embedded MathML files. Adding more options doesn't really help here, you only confuse users if they are lot of options of which none works properly.

Thanks. I had a more detailed look at the github repo and understand the limitations and the suggestions better. Great work by the way.
